# D3,js dialog modal not working any more

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, popup

I have a google map with popup alerts which used to work but for some reason isn't now.
It is supposed to be modal and have an x to close it. It ought to expand to include all text. This worked before but not any more.

It has a close button instead of the x. The text overflows the size of the window.

I copied the code from a working map but that did not help.

Here is the code:

```
function prettyAlert(p_message, p_title) {
p_title = p_title || "";
$(p_message).dialog({
   title: p_title,
   width:400,
   height:200,
   resizable: true,
   modal : true,
   close: function(ev, ui) {
     $(this).remove(); 
     }
  }).css("background", "lightgrey");
}
```

What could have broken this code. (It is embedded in a Drupal 7 page.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by completely removing the various jquery libraries I had added to the Drupal configuration and using the explicit  definitions in the code. I must have introduced something that conflicted with the behaviour of alerts.